# Laravel syntax error,not working

Tags: laravel-5

FatalErrorException in line 35: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '('

## View Products In Department

```
    </section>
    <hr/>
    <table class="table table-paper table-condensed table-bordered">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>@lang('viewproductlocations.Product Name')</th>
            <th>Department Name</th>
            <th>Quantity</th>
            <th>Created At</th>
            <th>@lang('viewproductlocations.Updated At')</th>

        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

        <?php $i = 1; ?>
        @foreach ($productsInDepartments as $productsInDepartment)
            <tr class="">
            <th scope="row">{{$i}}</th>
            @foreach ($productsInDepartment->present()->groupAndSumUpProductsInDepartments as departmentProduct)

                <td>{{$departmentProduct->product->productName}}</td>
                <td>{{$departmentProduct->totalAmount}}</td>
                @endforeach

                        <td>
                            {{$productsInDepartment->name}}
                        </td>

                        <td>{{Carbon::parse($productsInDepartment->created_at)->format('d/m/Y')}} </td>
                        <td>{{Carbon::parse($productsInDepartment->updated_at)->format('d/m/Y')}} </td>
                <?php $i++; ?>
            </tr>
        @endforeach

        </tbody>
    </table>
@endsection
```

I am getting this error please help me, I am getting a syntax error.FatalErrorException

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve my question. I had to loop though the results I was getting which was a list and the syntax error was coming from the face that I left an else out

Answer (score 0):

Please post the fullCode and highlight the line 35.
But i think you should check this part

```
@foreach ($productsInDepartment->present()->groupAndSumUpProductsInDepartments as departmentProduct)
```

try adding ->get()

```
 @foreach ($productsInDepartment->present()->groupAndSumUpProductsInDepartments->get() as departmentProduct)
```